# Did the avenue of the Gods exist?

Tags: egypt, monument

In the recent movie, Exodus: Gods and Kings a scene is shown, presumably in Memphis(?) depicting an avenue of the gods, terminated in a pylon. Did such a place actually exist?

[image: avenue of the gods]

Comment: Well, it is clear that the Egyptians did take a picture, isn't that enough? :-p

Comment: Why the close votes? Looks like a perfectly good question to me.

Comment: @Lohoris not a closer myself, but I would think that a scene of a Hollywood blockbuster sheldom has the minimal credibility to be worth discussing. If we are up to debate all of the historical references that appear in Hollywood movies and nowhere else then we open the way to lot of "garbage" questions. If the scene was part of a recreation for a documentary, the question could have some value.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can say, the only historically supported template that the scene was based on was the [Avenue of Sphinxes](https://www.google.cz/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22avenue%20of%20sphinxes%22%20gods&gws_rd=ssl) in Luxor (previously known as Thebes). The statues of sphinxes were there and they are still there while the additional statues of Gods were being moved there for special events.